# Read CSS classes from child element in Angular2

Tags: angular

Is there a more clever way of retrieving template component classes than using `nativeElement` reference:

`this.classes= elm.nativeElement.getAttribute('class');`

Which will return list of classes in string form, but I believe there is much more clever way of doing that...

Background:
I'm trying to set `type` property of `input type="password"` basing on `ng-pristine` class without using CSS. So it's basically toggling between `text` and `password` basing on `ng-pristine`.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea if this Angular 2 or later. The element provides such a status. https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#pristine

Comment: You can try `<input #inp="ngForm" [type]="inp.pristine ? 'text' : 'phone'">`, but no guarantees this will do anything useful.

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer I choose to read `dirty` property of FormControl. Works fine. If no further solutions will pop out I'' post it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do what you want:

```
<input #inp="ngForm" [type]="inp.pristine ? 'text' : 'phone'">
```